Getting 504 error on accessing api of backend deployed at azure app service minimal express project
I have deployed my backend (express ) app on app service azure , It shows it's successful , but when i use domain to call api call than it takes infinite time til l504 error shows .
code sources
here image of how it's behave = 
Showing 504 error after some time =
Trying to deploy backend with simple get route to test azure deployment

Are you deploying to Azure Windows App Service or Linux?

Provide the code and error in code format not in images.

Add this line const port = process.env.PORT || 3000  to your code. You are hard-coded the port.

I tried your code and deployed it to the Azure App Service, and it was successful.
If you are deploying to Windows, add the following line to Azure Web app AppSettings as shown below.
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true.


I added the following line to your code:
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

Below is Complete index.js code .
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
res.send("Hello From server")
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server is listning "))

Azure Windows Web app Output:

Azure Linux Web App Output:


@Mohammad Rizabul Is your Issue resolved.
